# QTreeWidget that contains widgets and set row height issue

Tags: qt, height, row, qtreewidget

Setting row height is more or less trivial via inherit from QItemDelegate.

The problem is that I can make the row size bigger but I cannot make it smaller if I add a widget inside.

Any tip on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your widget `QWidget::minimumSize().height()` is bigger than you want to set in your row height?

Also, maybe you will post some related code?